# MinGW error: 'min' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, max, std, min

I'm trying to convert some VC++ 6 code to a console app using only the standard libraries but am getting the following error from MinGW (whatever version is supplied with the Code::Blocks 10.05 IDE):

```
error: 'min' is not a member of 'std'
```

This is related to the following line of code:

```
L.Precision=std::min(1.e-4,0.001*res);
```

`L.Precision` is a `double`, and `res` is a `double`. Previously this line was:

```
L.Precision=min(1.e-4,0.001*res);
```

But this gives the error:

```
error: 'min' was not declared in this scope
```

Here are the headers in the file in question:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
//#include<algorithm.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "complex.h"
#include "mesh.h"
#include "spars.h"
#include "FemmeDocCore.h"
```

I understand that this may be related to some macros defined in the file `windef.h`, but correct me if I'm wrong about this.

What exactly can I do about this? I'm relatively new to C++, and am not even sure where `windef.h` is called for instance, I presume this is just needed for every windows program and is added at some point by MinGW. I want the final code to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should uncomment and fix `#include <algorithm>`, (without the .h) which is where `std::min` is declared.

This has absolutely nothing to do with MinGW or GCC or Windows, this is standard C++ stuff. If you hit any other errors like this, search for the missing identifier on http://en.cppreference.com/w/.

Also: use `<cmath>` and `<cstdio>`, and avoid `malloc` and friends, use `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem (i.e. header should indeed have been #include <algorithm> doh!). I'm using malloc because the code already has lots of calls to 'free' and 'calloc' etc. Is this a big problem, or can I leave it as it is? This isn't my code, it's someone else's.

Comment: @crobar: well, it's not wrong, just out of place. If it's not broken, don't fix it. Especially not if it's not your own code.