# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'complex.h': No such file or directory ..\lapacke\include\lapacke.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, fatal-error, lapack, lapacke

I built DLLs & Libs of LAPACKE for my Visual Studio 2008 based on the following link:

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/

After building LAPACKE, I tested as below and it passed the tests:

[image]

After building, I have the following files available:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I used the following tips in my Visual Studio 2008:

[image]

Now I have the following Visual Studio 2008 project:

[image]

I have the following pieces of C++ code in my project:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I comment out the line `#include "lapacke.h"` the executable builds and I get the following console output:

[image]

However, when I don't comment out `#include "lapacke.h"`I get the following errors:

[image]

Error location is line 73 of `lapacke.h` shown below:

[image]

I appreciate any help.

---

**EDIT:**

Even after including `#include <cstdlib>` before `#include "lapacke.h"`, the same errors happen:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

On the following links some people have discussed an issue which looks relevant:

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2284

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4221

---

**EDIT**

in the file `lapacke.h` the following statements are available for complex types.

```
/* Complex types are structures equivalent to the
* Fortran complex types COMPLEX(4) and COMPLEX(8).
*
* One can also redefine the types with his own types
* for example by including in the code definitions like
*
* #define lapack_complex_float std::complex<float>
* #define lapack_complex_double std::complex<double>
*
* or define these types in the command line:
*
* -Dlapack_complex_float="std::complex<float>"
* -Dlapack_complex_double="std::complex<double>"
*/

#ifndef LAPACK_COMPLEX_CUSTOM

/* Complex type (single precision) */
#ifndef lapack_complex_float
#include <complex.h>
#define lapack_complex_float    float _Complex
#endif

#ifndef lapack_complex_float_real
#define lapack_complex_float_real(z)       (creal(z))
#endif

#ifndef lapack_complex_float_imag
#define lapack_complex_float_imag(z)       (cimag(z))
#endif

lapack_complex_float lapack_make_complex_float( float re, float im );

/* Complex type (double precision) */
#ifndef lapack_complex_double
#include <complex.h>
#define lapack_complex_double   double _Complex
#endif

#ifndef lapack_complex_double_real
#define lapack_complex_double_real(z)      (creal(z))
#endif

#ifndef lapack_complex_double_imag
#define lapack_complex_double_imag(z)       (cimag(z))
#endif

lapack_complex_double lapack_make_complex_double( double re, double im );

#endif
```

I modified the header file as below:

[image]

However I receive the following error:

[image]

The above error happens at the following location:

[image]

I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

---

**EDIT:**

Finally solved the problem by adding `#include <complex>` as shown below. By the way, this post helped me to figure it out: [MinGW error: 'min' is not a member of 'std'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570139/mingw-error-min-is-not-a-member-of-std)

[image]

Rebuilds without any problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lapacke` is C code, not C++. Visual C++ has only limited support for C, and does not support `_Complex`. In C++, you'd use `std::complex<float>`.

Defining `LAPACK_COMPLEX_CUSTOM` may skip the use of `_Complex`, according to the code you've shown.

PS. please include source code in your question, not images.

Comment: I'm going to try `std::complex<float>`

Comment: I tried `std::complex<float>` and I updated the question with the results. I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Solved the problem and updated the question with the solution.